# Delete files that end with a certain string via SSH

Tags: images, filenames, ssh

I have a plugin on WordPress that smushes all my images. The problem is, that for some reason, there's no option to remove the original images from the server after the smush.

The plugin adds the string "unsmushed" to every image uploaded. Is there a command that could be launched via SSH to automatically delete all these images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` command will find all the images.  Run it like this, replacing `some/directory/` with the where the images are actually located (like `public/images/` or `/var/www/mysite/wp-content/`)

```
find some/directory/ -name "*unsmushed*"
```

Once you are happy that it has found the correct files, add the `rm` (remove) command to it to delete them:

```
find some/directory/ -name "*unsmushed*" -exec rm {} \;
```